# How to get git commit logs for particular project

Tags: git, github

Actually I have a git server running onto remote machine. I have installed git client onto my local and using command line to pull the projects using cloned URI.

Suppose I want to get the log details to view if project was updated in last few hours before I perform any pull(required for continuous integration). I am not finding any proper solution to it. Please support.

Answer (score 0):

this will tell you if there has been updates in the remote upstream, if the branch is tracking a remote branch.

```
git fetch --dry-run
```

you can actually get the branch, but not bring it into your local branch and view it's log with

```
git fetch
git log ..FETCH_HEAD --oneline
```

of course after all this you can pull as normal. see

```
git help fetch
```